# Create user from administrator and send email

Tags: user, emails

In Joomla 3, when creating a `User` from the administration panel I want him to receive a confirmation email.

In global configuration I set `New User Account Activation` to `Self` and `Send Password` to `Yes` but still not receiving the email.

The server mail settings are correct as I am able to send messages through the contact form.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do any other emails get sent by Joomla?

Comment: @TMichel, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 5):

The default behavior is that Joomla will send out an email to new users when created from the admin area (to the email in the "Email" field of the user settings).

There are a couple of reasons I can think of if you don't receive the message:

1. **User plugin settings**
   Locate the plugin **User - Joomla** in the plugin manager, and make sure it's set to send email notifications on user create:

   [image]

   [image]
2. Double check that Joomla can send out messages (email settings in *Global configuration* -> *Server* -> *Mail settings*).
3. Make sure the email entered in the user settings is correct (this is where the notification is sent)
4. Check your spam folder